# Excel formulas in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwings, vba

I have been searching all day for a solution to this problem, and I can't seem to find any solution.My original goal was to find a way to use excel autofill through a python library but that seemed impossible.

So far I have tried xlwings and openpyxl to do the following : write an extremely simple excel formula to a sheet. I know I can do the same as what the formula does inside python, but I want people who open the excel to see the formula, so I don't want it to disappear.

```
=IF(AB41<>"";CONCATENATE(AB41;".";AC41);"")
```

Using `openpyxl` the file always gets corrupted, and excel repairs it by deleting the formulas.
Using `xlwings` I get a special error (see below).
I don't understand why this has to be so difficult. The libraries just have to print the formula to the cell, and let excel do the interpreting afterwards.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/David/Google Drive/Jobs/1.Efe/Transporte/0.MODEL/rungams7.py", line 109, in <module>
    FLOWNREL("AD48","AD109",ws10)
  File "C:/Users/David/Google Drive/Jobs/1.Efe/Transporte/0.MODEL/rungams7.py", line 65, in FLOWNREL
    ws.range((i,col)).value = '=IF('+cell2.get_address(False, False) + '<>"";0;"")'
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1495, in value
    conversion.write(data, self, self._options)
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 35, in write
    pipeline(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\framework.py", line 66, in __call__
    stage(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 91, in __call__
    self._write_value(ctx.range, ctx.value, scalar)
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 71, in _write_value
    rng.raw_value = value
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1116, in raw_value
    self.impl.raw_value = data
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 709, in raw_value
    self.xl.Value = data
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 98, in __setattr__
    return setattr(self._inner, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\David\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 565, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

CODE in `XLWINGS` :

```
def FLOWNREL(startcell,endcell,ws):
    startrow = coordinate_from_string(startcell)[1]
    endrow=coordinate_from_string(endcell)[1]
    col = column_index_from_string(coordinate_from_string(startcell)[0])
    for i in range(startrow, endrow + 1, 1):
        cell2 = ws.range(i,col-2)
        cell3 = ws.range(i,col-1)
        print(i,col,cell2.get_address(False,False),cell3.get_address(False,False))
        # ws.range((i,col)).value='=IF('+cell2.get_address(False,False)+'<>"";CONCATENATE('+cell2.get_address(False,False)+';".";'+cell3.get_address(False,False)+');"")'
        ws.range((i,col)).value = '=IF('+cell2.get_address(False, False) + '<>"";0;"")'
        print(ws.range(i,col).value)

wb = xw.Book(dir_path+"\\Input EfE.xlsx")
ws10=wb.sheets["_FlowsNRel"]
FLOWNREL("AD48","AD109",ws10)
wb.save()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with xlwings but in VBA you add formulas by using the `.formula` property instead of the `.value` property and then use `,` instead of `;` like `=IF(AB41<>"", CONCATENATE(AB41, ".", AC41), "")`. Not sure if this works in xlwings but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that doesn't work in either xlwings or openpyxl.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on the tip of PEH, I managed to find the error.
The European excel uses ";" and the American uses "," to separate different parts of formulas.
Even though in excel I use the ";" in python it seems that I should use "," for it to work in openpyxl.

So for future readers : Be careful between the differences in excel formulas between the european and American version!

Thanks!

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-formulae